# Clear Safari history & iTunes login

Tags: itunes, safari

I have installed Yosemite OS on my Mac and I encounter the following problem. Whenever I clear Safari history, then I always have to login to iTunes if I want to use the online services (e.g. internet music or online radio).

Is this a bug or that's the way it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **History > Clear History and Website Data**, which is the only obvious option to clear history at least in Safari 8, then this is its intended behaviour.

However, if you wish to remove your history but *leave intact other data* such as login cookies, you can do this by selecting **History > Show History**. Single-click on one of the entries to highlight it, and then click **Edit > Select All**. This will highlight all of your history. Click **Edit > Delete** to clear them all out (it might take a few seconds).

Answer (score 1):

That is sadly the way it works.

Answer (score 1):

Same behavior here. I believe that is how it works. To correct your question: **clearing history** won't affect that, only after **clearing all cookies and data**.